# List view with tile view style, sub item does not appear?

Tags: api, winapi, listview

I'm working on `ListView` with pure `win32` `api`. But when I set `ListView` with tile view. then the sub item does not appear beside item.
My code below:

```
ListView_SetView(m_hwndListview,LV_VIEW_TILE);
//Set tile view info
SIZE size = { 150, 75 };
LVTILEVIEWINFO tileViewInfo = {0};

tileViewInfo.cbSize   = sizeof(tileViewInfo);
tileViewInfo.dwFlags  = LVTVIF_FIXEDSIZE;
tileViewInfo.dwMask   = LVTVIM_COLUMNS | LVTVIM_TILESIZE;
tileViewInfo.cLines   = 3;
tileViewInfo.sizeTile = size;

//Set tile info
LVTILEINFO lvti = {0};
int order[2];
order[0]=2;
order[1]=1;
lvti.cbSize = sizeof(LVTILEINFO);
lvti.iItem = 0;
lvti.cColumns = 2;
lvti.piColFmt =  LVCFMT_LEFT;
lvti.puColumns = PUINT(order);

ListView_SetTileInfo(m_hwndListview, &lvti);
ListView_SetTileViewInfo(m_hwndListview, &tileViewInfo);
```

Does anyone have idea to solve this problem?
Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

`lvti.piColFmt` should be a pointer to an array of column format values, not a single value. In your case it could be something like this:

```
int colfmt[2];
colfmt[0] = LVCFMT_LEFT;
colfmt[1] = LVCFMT_LEFT;
lvti.piColFmt = colfmt;
```

Hope that helps!